# Find last time occured based on a time window with spark/scala for each group

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I want to find the last/previous time a login attempt occurred from a  specific (user and device) based on timestamp window.

```
For example my initial dataset looks like this:

+--------+-------+-------------------+-------+
|username| device|         attempt_at|   stat|
+--------+-------+-------------------+-------+
|   user1|     pc|2018-01-02 07:44:27| failed|
|   user1|     pc|2018-01-02 07:44:10|Success|
|   user2| iphone|2017-12-23 16:58:08|Success|
|   user2| iphone|2017-12-23 16:58:30|Success|
|   user2| iphone|2017-12-23 16:58:50| failed|
|   user1|android|2018-01-02 07:44:37| failed|
|   user1|android|2018-01-05 08:33:47| failed|
+--------+-------+-------------------+-------+

//code
val df1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("user1", "pc", "2018-01-02 07:44:27", "failed"),
  ("user1", "pc", "2018-01-02 07:44:10", "Success"),
  ("user2", "iphone", "2017-12-23 16:58:08", "Success"),
  ("user2", "iphone", "2017-12-23 16:58:30", "Success"),
  ("user2", "iphone", "2017-12-23 16:58:50", "failed"),
  ("user1", "android", "2018-01-02 07:44:37", "failed"),
  ("user1", "android", "2018-01-05 08:33:47", "failed")
)).toDF("username", "device", "attempt_at", "stat")
```

**What I want**

1 hr and 7 days windows where I can find previous attempts in timestamp for each particular user and device. Basically grouped by user and device.

For example: For 'user1' and device 'pc', for the dataset above, the previous attempt for both 1 hr window and 7 days would be '2018-01-02 07:44:27'.

But from device 'android' for user1, the previous attempt for 7 days would be '2018-01-02 07:44:27' but nothing for a  1 hr window since there are no attempts in the last 1 hr for user1 from android.

**Expected output datasets**

```
// 1 hr window for last known attempt
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------------------+
|username| device|           attempt_at| previous_attempt_at|
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------------------+
|   user1|     pc|  2018-01-02 07:44:10| 2018-01-02 07:44:27|
|   user2| iphone|  2017-12-23 16:58:50| 2017-12-23 16:58:30|
+--------+-------+---------------------+--------------------+

// 7 days window for last known attempt
+--------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
|username| device |           attempt_at| previous_attempt_at|
+--------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
|   user1|     pc |  2018-01-02 07:44:10| 2018-01-02 07:44:27|
|   user1| android|  2018-01-05 08:33:47| 2018-01-02 07:44:37|
|   user2|  iphone|  2017-12-23 16:58:50| 2017-12-23 16:58:30|
+--------+--------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

**What I tried:**

I tried using window over 1 hr windows using 'last'. It gives the current rows timestamp but not the previous based on the window.

```
val w = (Window.partitionBy("username", "device")
                 .orderBy(col("attempt_at").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
                   .rangeBetween(-3600, 0)
                 )

val df2 = df1.withColumn("previous_attempt_at", last("attempt_at").over(w))
```

Comment: @eliasah If you think so. I removed my vote then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `.rangeBetween(-3600, 0)` with `.rangeBetween(-3600, -1)`.

0 is `CURRENT ROW` so it always be the last.

Comment: does -1 represent 1 second from current row? Because 3600 seconds is 1 hour.

Comment: Yes, it does. You convert your data to epoch timestamp.